# I am getting stack overflow error in the following code ... not sure what am i missing here?

Tags: java, string, recursion

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RemoveDuplicates {
    public static boolean ar[]=new boolean[26];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        DeDupe(s,0,"");

    }
    public static void DeDupe(String s,int idx,String s1)
    {
        if(idx==s.length())
        {
            System.out.println(s1);
            return;
        }
        if(ar[s.charAt(idx)-'a']==false)
        {
            s1+=s.charAt(idx);
            //System.out.print(s1);
            ar[s.charAt(idx)-'a']=true;
        }
        DeDupe(s,idx++,s1);
    }

}
```

Trying to solve remove duplicates from string question using recursion... i am getting stack overflow error ..added the base condition not sure what am i missing

Comment: Duplicate words or duplicate characters?

Comment: We can't run debugger on code which *doesn't compile*. Note that there is no *declaration of `i`* variable in your example. There is `idx`.

Comment: Anyway as already mentioned in previous (now deleted) comment, at `DeDupe(s,idx++,s1);` the `idx++` returns original value of `idx`, not incremented one. You need `idx+1` or `++idx` instead.

Comment: Assuming you want to deduplicate characters: The base case is that a single character is a deduplicated string. In case of 2 or more characters, deduplicate substring 0 to n-2 then check that if character n is contained in the deduplicated substring

Answer (score 4):

You are use the "postfix" unary operator on your recursive call to `DeDupe`.

```java
DeDupe(s,i++,s1);
```

So, essentially, `i` stays at `0`, and loops indefinitely.

Change it to a "prefix" operator, or just `i + 1`, to get a result.

Answer (score 0):

I see that "DeDupe" method of yours is void,
but even the String is an object in java,
it is not passed by a reference but as a value,
because String is immutable.
And after all the processing, no result is produced anyway.

Comment: I am not sure if i got the point correctly but i am not trying to return any value to main